# Java io using read()

Tags: java, io

I was trying this code snippet-

```
import java.io.*;

class demo
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
            {
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                int c;
                do
                    {
                        c= (char)br.read();
                        System.out.println(c);
                    }while(c!='q');
            }
    }
```

Now when I give input-22
output is- 50
50
13
10

I understand the output 50, 50 but why the the compiler is printing 13 and 10 ?
Kindly help.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a `BufferedReader` here.

Comment: Why don't I need a Buffered Reader? "br" in br.read() is an object of buffered Reader! Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: But it doesn't need to be. Decorating the `InputStreamReader` with a `BufferedReader` is pointless as you do not use `br` _as a_ `BufferedReader` but rather as a `Reader`.

Comment: I think using Scanner class would be much better here if you want to only read the input.

Answer (score 4):

I think 13 and 10 are CR/LF: the end of the line.

Comment: Yes I get it! but they are carriage return and feed ASCII code shouldn't be printed according to the snippet. Please suggest that how can I get rid of them!

Comment: @user3788040 you typed `22` then pressed `Enter`, right?

Answer (score 1):

your input is

```
22<enter>
```

so your ascii for 2 is 50 hence 22 50 50

Pressing Enter causes Windows to store a carriage return code (ASCII 13) followed by a new-line code (ASCII 10) in the key buffer and hence you see 13 and 10 in the output.

You could also refer a good blog here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075069/core-java/the-ins-and-outs-of-standard-input-output.html